# Why does splice method works on const (constant) array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
let selected_user = '11';
const arrayOfUsers = ['11', '12', '13'];
console.log(arrayOfUsers); // ['11', '12', '13']
let indexMainUser = arrayOfUsers.indexOf(selected_user);
arrayOfUsers.splice(indexMainUser, 1);
console.log(arrayOfUsers); //  ['12', '13']
```

I have the above code in JavaScript and I am wondering why does a constant array gets modified with splice method?

Comment: const stops the variable from being reassigned. It does not stop you modifying the contents of that variable.

Comment: [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) stops the variable from being *reassigned*.

Comment: array and object can be modified but their memory address remains the same.